# Conditionals in String - Java Properties File

Tags: java, properties

Have a java property like below

**sample.properties**

```
query={name} in {address:-}
```

Currently using [StrSubstitutor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html) to replace the values

```
 valuesMap.put("name", "Har");
 valuesMap.put("address", "Park Street");
 String queryString= properties.get("query");
 StrSubstitutor sub = new StrSubstitutor(valuesMap);
 String resolvedString = sub.replace(queryString);
```

resolvedString = Har in Park Street

What I need is that if the "address" isn't available, the resolved string should be as :

**resolvedString = Har** instead of **resolvedString = Har in**

Is it possible to achieve this using StrSubstitutor or by anyother means like using template engine?

Do not want any Java code dependency as the query pattern can change.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a way not to loose generality:

```
query1={name} in {address}
query2={name}
...
String queryString;
if (valueMap.get("address") == "") {
    queryString= properties.get("query2");
} else {
    queryString= properties.get("query1");
}
StrSubstitutor sub = new StrSubstitutor(valuesMap);
String resolvedString = sub.replace(queryString);
```

in this way even if in the future queries have to change, you'll be able to manage the difference between the two cases.

EDIT: if in the future you want to add new properties such in your comment: 
{name} as {alias} in {address}

I think a way to proceed could be to put even "as" and "in" into the query:
query = {name} {as} {alias} {in} {address}

and the populate the database or the valueMap (don't know where the data come from in your application)) in the right way (so {as}="" when no "alias" and {in}="" when no address). Would that be feasible for you?

Comment: Say if in future I add another param in the query like "{name} as {alias} in {address}" where the alias is optional, I would have to change the java code to add another conditional check. Is it possible to avoid code change by using any library and specifying the rules in property file ?

Comment: added a suggestion into my answer above